# How to cache warmup in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, symfony-1.4

I have a symfony 1.4.8 version application. Is there support for cache warmup in this version of symfony or any other alternative by which we can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Cache warming is nothing but generating new cache for your application.

> Run this command to clear the existing cache and warm it up

```
php symfony cc
```

or

```
php symfony clear-cache
```